# Getting quite a few SQL Azure connection issues today, and forced disconnections, how to get more information from MS and also how to monitor?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We use the Northern Europe Azure Data Centre. We use SQL Azure Web Edition with Websites. Today we seem to be getting quite a few SQL Azure disconnections with error code 10054:

Symptom:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Mitigation:

```
Implement retry logic in your application
```

What is frustrating about this is that I cannot find any MS Azure Alerts to an issue. I suspect their SQL Azure systems will be ringing alarms. I have looked in [Azure Status](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/status/) and Management Services.

Are there other places I can looks for these alerts, and also what is the best way to notify MS that there is an issue.

Finally how are folks monitoring SQL Azure for issues, throttling, disconnects etc? I have come across cotega.com.

P.s as a side note, I do understand the importance of putting in "retry logic", and but cannot happen quickly, and my code could be improved in this respect. However something does seem wrong with SQL Azure today. Up until now, the service has been by and large great.

EDIT 1:

Error Code:

```
Error Number:10054,State:0,Class:20
```

EDIT 2:

I think the moral of this story is to not underestimate the impact of throttling and scaling out, rather than scaling up, of SQL Azure services, and the importance of implementing retry logic/ MS Transient pattern logic. Still, this variable performance is a little frustrating, but perhaps this is the cloud for you, although with the new Data Tiers you can pay for more predictability.

EDIT 3: Interestingly SQL Azure is not performing more efficiently with no errors being noticed. So an issue with Azure. However difficult to identify apart from application error logs. I use Elmah.

Comment: what's the error number, i think you're throthling

Comment: Thanks for this.... I have added this is EDIT1, but it is 10054. We have not suffered from this for a long time, and usage has not suddenly gone up.... So the symptom feels more like a router issue, or definately a temporary network/capacity issue.... If I was cynical I could suggest that resources are being pulled from the old SQL Azure Web Edition setups in favour of the new data tiers, but surely not....

Comment: The error code is not a throttling error code. You can check the view sys.event_log in the master DB of the logical server to see if throttling occured or not.

Comment: @JanEngelsberg, This is incredibly useful. I was unaware of this. Digging into this table I find my disconnect errors map to "reconfiguration" event in the log table with a severity of 2. The description is "The session has been terminated due to a database reconfiguration." So this seems that Microsoft is doing something to the database/Database Server. There were quite a few "reconfigurations" between 10/03 and 12/03, but it seems to have stopped now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconfigurations happen when upgrades are rolled-out to the service or when databases are load-balanced to avoid noisy neighbor issues.

The view sys.event_log in the master DB has information on why the disconnects happened (reconfiguration vs. throttling, etc.).

Service outages are reported in the portal.

Comment: This is most useful. Thanks. Only comment I would make is that I thought that due to clustering of SQL Server instances, and multiple saves (3 I believe) then I would have thought that upgrades could happen on one node at a time without affecting overall service. The load balancer could then redirect to working instances. This is how Websites work, but then again SQL Azure may be completely different in how it handles service resiliency.

Comment: Is this to be considered SQL Azure standard behaviour, and a function of using it, and therefore one should implement "Retry Logic" in one's application to mitigate ?

Comment: Having retry logic is general best practice when developing in the cloud. Besides updates to the system and load-balancing there are other reasons why you might have to lose the connecting to the DB, for example hardware failures, short network outages etc.